# How to fix error Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach does not exist. Attaching multiple items

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to attach "items model" to "events model.

Item Model:

```
public function events()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event', 'event_item');
}
```

Event Model

```
public function items()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'event_item');
}
```

User Model

```
public function items()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'user_id');
}
```

EventsController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  // Get user
  $user = $request->user();

  // Create event
  $event = Event::create(array_merge($request->all(), ['user_id' => $user->id]));

  // Attach items to event
  $user->items()->attach($event->id);

}
```

My user has multiple items. All user items need to be attached to events on store function.
I get this error Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out, easy mistake actually. I want to attach items to events but in my original question I have users attaching to items.

Changed this:

```
// Attach items to event
$user->items()->attach($event->id);
```

To this:

```
// Attach items to event
$event->items()->attach($user->items);
```

Works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

User Model:

```
 return $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'item_id');
```

Comment: Hmmm.. no user_id is correct. Also removing the foreign_key there does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `User model` items function has to return a BelongsToMany relationship in order to use attach().

User Model:

```
public function items() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item');
    }
```